# Can't install Dropbox plugin for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, plugins, dropbox

I'm trying to add the latest (v5.1.1) Dropbox plugin to my Android Studio install (Bumblebee 2021.1.1) on Win10.  I downloaded the .jar file from releases/v5.1.1 folder to an empty folder, then tried to install it using this method: from the Studio main menu I chose Plugins, selected the gear icon followed by Install Plugin From Disk, browsed to the .jar file location, selected it then pressed OK.  I got an error message: "Fail to load plugin from file dropbox-sdk-java-5.1.1.jar".  I tried installing the -5.1.1-javadoc.jar file using the same method, with the same result.  I don't need the sources, I just want to use the SDK.  Any ideas?  TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you meant "Android Studio" instead of "Visual Studio"?

If so, it sounds like you're attempting to install [the Dropbox Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java) as a plugin to Android Studio itself. The Dropbox Java SDK is not an Android Studio plugin though. It is a package for connecting to the Dropbox API from your Java app.

To install the Dropbox package in your app, you should use Maven or Gradle, [as instructed here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java#setup).

The Dropbox Java SDK also comes with [an example Android app that uses the Dropbox package](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/DropboxAndroid).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Greg; your answer pointed me in the right direction.  I had already added an 'implementation' directive to my Gradle file as per the directions on GitHub.  However, I took the instruction to add the directive by editing my "project's build.gradle" too literally; I added it to the Project build.gradle file instead of adding it to the Module build.gradle.  Problem solved!